# Animate jumps in Chrome - jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm having a small problem in Google Chrome with my animation.

Here are the functions I'm using:

```
function moveRight(){

var x=parseInt($('#position').val(),10);
if(x==-7200){x=0;}
else{x-=900;}
$('#position').val(x);
$('#slides').animate({'left': x + 'px'}, 1000 );

}


function moveLeft(){

var x=parseInt($('#position').val(),10);
if(x==0){x=-7200;}
else{x+=900;}
$('#position').val(x);
$('#slides').animate({'left': x + 'px'}, 1000 );
}
```

I have a hidden input on the page that keeps the current position of the div that slides left and right.

About the 3rd or 4th time you click the right button (moveRight();) you will notice it jumps and then animates. (view page here: http://ghcnow.com/savings-advantage.php)  It doesn't do this in Firefox, seems to be related to Chrome.

I downloaded the most recent version of jquery (1.7.2)

Not sure what else to do short of rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: "I downloaded the most recent version of jquery (1.7.2)"   1.8.3 is the last

Comment: I don't see the issue in Chrome.  I click the right arrow multiple times and it just animates normally each time.  Why are you keeping the position in an input field?  You can either use a global variable or `$("#slides").data()'.  Then, you won't have to parse it each time either.  The DOM is not very efficient for storing data.

Comment: This could be due to a slower machine

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the comments.  So I tried it on my other computer and it animates correctly. I've updated to 1.8.3 (thanks roasted).  I've determined that it happens when you zoom in on the page, still only happens in Chrome.  So anyone not looking at the page at 100% zoom is going to have issues.  Not as big of an issue now but still curious to know if there is a fix.

Comment: @jfriend00 The answer to y our question would more or less be because I'm not a everyday programmer lol. Since your post I looked at getting the x position of the #slides but it's relative to the window. I wouldn't have trouble moving left or right but I'm not sure how I would know when I would be at the end of the slides.  Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue but got it solved by changing

```
position:relative
```

to

```
position:absolute
```

dont know whether it's the same issue